# Do we always need to point dangling pointers to null?

Tags: c++, pointers

Say I have the following C++ code:

```
void f() {
MyClass *p = new Class();
delete p;
}
```

Here, I avoided a memory leak because I deleted whatever that was in the heap. My question is, do I need to make p a null pointer, to avoid it from being a dangling pointer, like so: p = nullptr;

I think the answer is I don't need to make it point to null because when we go out of scope of the function, everything that's on the stack is deleted automatically, meaning that the pointer p is automatically deleted.

Comment: That's correct. Dangling pointers are only an issue when you might accidentally dereference it later.

Comment: `p` is not a dangling pointer, since it is not being used anymore after the `delete`. But if you were still using it after the `delete`, then yes, you would have to set it to null so that later code can know whether it is still pointing at a valid `MyClass` object or not.

Comment: You do not have to do it, but sometimes you want to.

Comment: No, you do not **need** to set a dangling pointer to `nullptr`, as long as you do not dereference it after the delete.  You may want to set it to `nullptr` if you could use the pointer later, and check to make sure it isn't `nullptr` (used as a sentinel value).  But in the example provided, it is all contained within the routine.

Comment: In my experience, you never need to assign pointers to null after delete occurs. This is assuming that code is all handling correctly.

Comment: which is a big assumption ;)

Comment: Note: If you haven't already, look into smart pointers like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). They're very helpful in guaranteeing a resource is freed after everyone (with degrees of "everyone" varying by the type of smart pointer used) is done using it.